# xpages page auto refresh after "IDLE" for session of time (5-10 minute)

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Do xpages have a session of time? I do some research on "session timeout" about the xpages. But i not sure, is my xpages auto "refresh" after idle for few minute is related with it?

**Experience:**

1. I use google chrome to run on my xpages page.
2. My xpages page have around 20 field.
3. I look for information around few minute, after that try to fill it in, but when i click on the field, all the field that i filled in before it become
   "empty" and look like the page is auto refresh.

**Question here**

1. Do anyone face this auto refresh problem before?
2. Do this related with session timeout/Expired?
3. If anyone face this problem before, how you guy solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [keepSessionAlive](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/extlib_controlref_keepsessionalive.html) to avoid session timeout. It causes the client to communicate with the server regularly so the server keeps the session open as long as the XPage is not closed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:keepSessionAlive id="keepSessionAlive1" delay="0"></xe:keepSessionAlive>
...
</xp:view>
```

`delay="0"` means the current session timeout value (specified on the XPages tab for Application Properties) minus 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the solution / suggestion, but may i know, do i need to do that on every xpage? for example, index.xsp  and etc page. Do xpages have some way using database setting to control all web page create using xpages?

Comment: Yes, it has to be on every XPage. Usually you have a CustomControl with keepSessionAlive and other general layout elements that is part of every XPage. This way you have this code on just one place.